# testing-library/react not working with all latest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

When I run my tests I get

```
Cannot find module 'react-dom/client' from 'node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js'
```

This is the line that triggers the error

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
```

I am using `latest` of the following dependencies

1. @testing-library/react
2. react
3. @types/react
4. react-dom
5. @types/react-dom
6. jest
7. @types/jest
8. ts-jest

Comment: Can you show your whole package json? Have you recently run a clean install (`npm ci`) of your packages?

Comment: I can answer questions about any deps, but I think it makes the issue confusing for future folks to have the whole dump. Yes, I have run `rm -rf node_modules && npm i`